# Problem with quotas from google cloud endpoint framework for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, metrics, quota, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm developing a simple api with GAE standard and Cloud Endpoint to test the available quota feature.
Here's the Java Code using the EndPoint Framework annotation:

```java
package com.example.skeleton;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.*;

@Api(
        name = "simpleapi",
        version = "v1",
        limitDefinitions = {
                @ApiLimitMetric(
                        name = "read-requests",
                        displayName = "Read requests",
                        limit = 10
                )
        }
)
public class MyApi {

  @ApiMethod(
          name = "hellosecuredWithQuotas",
          path = "hellosecuredWithQuotas",
          httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET,
          apiKeyRequired= AnnotationBoolean.TRUE,
          metricCosts = {
                  @ApiMetricCost(
                          name ="read-requests",
                          cost = 1
                  )
          }

  )
  public Message helloSecuredWithQuotas(@Named("name") String name) {
    return new Message("hello " + name);
  }
}
```

So given the @Api annotations the quotas is 10 requests per minute.

I deploy the App in GAE.

I Generate the OpenAPI json file (see below for the generated content) and deploy it to Cloud Endpoint using gcloud CLI.

Finally I use the generated client to call the endpoint in a loop which is calling the endpoint more than 10 times per minute.

... but unfortunately I never receive the expected "HTTP status code of 429 Too Many Requests".

```java
public class App {

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();

        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        Simpleapi simpleapi = new Simpleapi.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                .setApplicationName("test")
                .build();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++) {
            Message titi = simpleapi.hellosecuredWithQuotas("foobar" + System.currentTimeMillis()).setKey("my-api-key-here").execute();
            System.out.println(titi.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the generated openapi.json file:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "my-project-name-here.appspot.com"
  },
  "host": "my-project-name-here.appspot.com",
  "basePath": "/_ah/api",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/simpleapi/v1/hellosecuredWithQuotas": {
      "get": {
        "operationId": "SimpleapiHelloSecuredWithQuotas",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "name",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Message"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "api_key": []
          }
        ],
        "x-google-quota": {
          "metricCosts": {
            "read-requests": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "api_key": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "name": "key",
      "in": "query"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Message": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "x-google-management": {
    "metrics": [
      {
        "name": "read-requests",
        "valueType": "INT64",
        "metricKind": "GAUGE"
      }
    ],
    "quota": {
      "limits": [
        {
          "name": "read-requests",
          "metric": "read-requests",
          "values": {
            "STANDARD": 10
          },
          "unit": "1/min/{project}",
          "displayName": "Read requests"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same problem and have been unable to find a root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by setting the limit value in the ApiLimitMetric configuration to a value 100 or greater. If you'd like to have a maximum of 10 requests per minute, you should set the limit to 100 and the cost value in the ApiMetricCost configuration on the method to 10. This would give you the same ratio of 1/10 as listed in your original post.

Comment: This change was working when tested on my local dev environment, but once I pushed these changes to AppEngine, I receive the following error when instances are initialized: `com.google.api.control.Client start: The scheduler thread was unable to start. This means that metric reporting will only be done periodically after requests are served. If your API is low-traffic (below 1 query per second), this may result in delays in reporting.` I am not seeing any of the quota limits being enforced.